# Help with labels in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-3d, neuralnetwork

I'm using [PlotNeuralNet](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet) (with slightly modified Python code) to generate TikZ code for my neural network architecture. Currently, it generates this TikZ code (it is a simplified version of my full network architecture, but it works to illustrate my issues):

```latex
\documentclass[border=8pt, multi, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{../layers/}{init}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d} %for including external image 

\def\ConvColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\ConvReluColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,5;white,5}
\def\PoolColor{rgb:red,1;black,0.3}
\def\UnpoolColor{rgb:blue,2;green,1;black,0.3}
\def\FcColor{rgb:blue,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\FcReluColor{rgb:blue,5;red,5;white,4}
\def\SoftmaxColor{rgb:magenta,5;black,7}   
\def\SumColor{rgb:blue,5;green,15}

\newcommand{\copymidarrow}{\tikz \draw[-Stealth,line width=0.8mm,draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3}] (-0.3,0) -- ++(0.3,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{connection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw=\edgecolor,opacity=0.7]
\tikzstyle{copyconnection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3},opacity=0.7]

\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) 
    {Box={
        name=input,
        caption=ERA-5,
        xlabel={{20, }},
        ylabel=222,
        zlabel={{\qquad\qquad\qquad 531}},
        fill=white,
        height=8.88,
        width=0.8,
        depth=21.240000000000002
        }
    };

\node[canvas is zy plane at x=0, xscale=-1] (inputimage) at (0.16000000000000003,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4.248cm,height=1.7760000000000002cm]{../images/ERA-5.png}};

\pic[shift={(2.16,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) 
    {Box={
        name=dil1,
        caption= ,
        xlabel={{50, }},
        ylabel=222,
        zlabel={{\qquad\qquad\qquad 531}},
        fill={rgb:green,5;red,2.5;white,5},
        height=8.88,
        width=2.0,
        depth=21.240000000000002
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (input-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (dil1-west);

\pic[shift={(5.5600000000000005,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) 
    {Box={
        name=output,
        caption=Temperature distribution parameters,
        xlabel={{2, }},
        ylabel=444,
        zlabel={{\qquad\qquad\qquad 444}},
        fill=white,
        height=42.76,
        width=0.08,
        depth=42.76
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (dil1-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (output-west);

\node[canvas is zy plane at x=0, xscale=-1] (output) at (5.5760000000000005,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8.552cm,height=8.552cm]{../images/Predicted.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the file `Box.sty` from the [layers](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet/tree/master/layers) folder in the PlotNeuralNet repository:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{Box}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This Block can draw simple block of boxes with custom colors. 
% Can be used for conv, deconv etc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{Box/.pic={\tikzset{/boxblock/.cd,#1}
        \tikzstyle{box}=[every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.7},fill opacity=\opacity, pic actions,fill=\fill]
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\cubey*\scale}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\cubez*\scale}
   
        %Multiple concatenated boxes
        \foreach[count=\i,%
                 evaluate=\i as \xlabel using {array({\boxlabels},\i-1)},% 
                 evaluate=\unscaledx as \k using {\unscaledx*\scale+\prev}, remember=\k as \prev (initially 0)] 
                 \unscaledx in \cubex
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\unscaledx*\scale}
            \coordinate (a) at (\k-\x , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (b) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (c) at (\k    ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (d) at (\k    , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (e) at (\k    , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (f) at (\k    ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (g) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (h) at (\k-\x , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
        
            \draw [box] 
                (d) -- (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle     
                (d) -- (a) -- (h) -- (e) -- cycle
                %dotted edges
                (f) edge (g)
                (b) edge (g)
                (h) edge (g)    
            ;
            \path (b) edge ["\xlabel"',midway] (c);
            
            \xdef\LastEastx{\k} %\k persists as \LastEastx after loop 
        }%Loop ends
        \draw [box] (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (c) -- cycle; %East face of last box     
        
        \coordinate (a1) at (0 , \y/2 , \z/2);
        \coordinate (b1) at (0 ,-\y/2 , \z/2);
        \tikzstyle{depthlabel}=[pos=0,text width=14*\z,text centered,sloped]       
        
        \path (c) edge ["\small\zlabel"',depthlabel](f); %depth label
        \path (b1) edge ["\ylabel",midway] (a1);  %height label
        
        
        \tikzstyle{captionlabel}=[text width=15*\LastEastx/\scale,text centered]       
        \path (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,+\z/2) + (0,-25pt) coordinate (cap) 
        edge ["\textcolor{black}{ \bf \caption}"',captionlabel](cap) ; %Block caption/pic object label
         
        %Define nodes to be used outside on the pic object
        \coordinate (\name-west)   at (0,0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-east)   at (\LastEastx, 0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-north)  at (\LastEastx/2,\y/2,0);
        \coordinate (\name-south)  at (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,0);       
        \coordinate (\name-anchor) at (\LastEastx/2, 0,0) ;
        
        \coordinate (\name-near) at (\LastEastx/2,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-far)  at (\LastEastx/2,0,-\z/2);       
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearwest) at (0,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-neareast) at (\LastEastx,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farwest)  at (0,0,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-fareast)  at (\LastEastx,0,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-northeast) at (\name-north-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-northwest) at (\name-north-|\name-west);
        \coordinate (\name-southeast) at (\name-south-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-southwest) at (\name-south-|\name-west);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnortheast)  at (\LastEastx, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnortheast)   at (\LastEastx, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsoutheast)  at (\LastEastx,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsoutheast)   at (\LastEastx,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnorthwest)  at (0, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnorthwest)   at (0, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsouthwest)  at (0,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsouthwest)   at (0,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
    },
    /boxblock/.search also={/tikz},
    /boxblock/.cd,
    width/.store        in=\cubex,
    height/.store       in=\cubey,
    depth/.store        in=\cubez,
    scale/.store        in=\scale,
    xlabel/.store       in=\boxlabels,
    ylabel/.store       in=\ylabel,
    zlabel/.store       in=\zlabel,
    caption/.store      in=\caption,
    name/.store         in=\name,
    fill/.store         in=\fill,
    opacity/.store      in=\opacity,
    fill={rgb:red,5;green,5;blue,5;white,15},
    opacity=0.4,
    width=2,
    height=13,
    depth=15,
    scale=.2,
    xlabel={{"","","","","","","","","",""}},
    ylabel=,
    zlabel=,
    caption=,
    name=,
}
```

This LaTeX code generates the image

[image]

in which there are a couple of label-related things that I would like to improve:

1. The captions under the input and output layers are given way too little horizontal space. I would like to increase the amount of horizontal space given to these captions so that they don't end up on so many rows.
2. I would like to rotate the `ylabel` by 90 degrees counterclockwise, and also slide it slightly down along the box edge if necessary by a distance that I can choose per box.
3. I would like to make the `zlabel` to end up over the box instead of under the box, and closer to the upper right corner (but not all the way to the corner).

How can I address each of these points by modifying the generated LaTeX code, as well as modifying the LaTeX code in the repository? (In practice, I will modify the LaTeX code indirectly by modifying the Python code that generates it, but that is a technicality that's not really relevant to this question.)

Comment: I think these are questions for whomever created the `Box` pic. I don't see a good interface (i.e. styles) that effect those nodes. Even worse, the styles it does use 1. are defined inside of the code of the pic, 2. use deprecated `\tikzstyle` and 3. overwrite it anyway so you can't set them from the outside.

Comment: I had a similar consideration. Coding the drawing manually will probably result in different and simpler code. Don't know, if you could replace that in Python.

Comment: @MS-SPO Okay, if I code the drawing manually, how do I go ahead? I'm not very proficient in TikZ; that's why I asked for help here. But simultaneously, given the generated code and the code from `Box.sty`, wouldn't it be simpler to change in that code? I will probably want to extend my network in the future, and then I will probably use other functionality that has already been implemented in the repository.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I think either me or other members will come up with some code, soon. // You see, I can code manually good and bad code, and I can automate both. If so, I‘d prefer the good version.

Comment: @MS-SPO I would really appreciate the effort, but if you come up with completely new code, will I be able to use it? As I wrote, this is a simplified version of my whole network architecture, and is a MWE that shows the problems that I was experiencing when rendering the whole architecture. I still need to be able to render the rest of the architecture too.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever. Let me put it that way, as I see it. Whoever wrote that Tikz-generator for some reason made it somewhat complicated - which may be justified from a different perspective. Which means: that Tikz-code is hard to mantain or change; it's possible and remains somehow "ugly" (as a rule of thumb, good code tends to look beautiful). So far I did not dive into it for these reasons. Having reference code(s) gives you the opprotunity to adapt the generator. // So, it's up to you to make a basic decision.

Comment: @MS-SPO Hm, maybe it would be better to start fresh from good code if you think the code here is bad. But as you maybe see, I'm not very proficient myself (yet) in TikZ, so I will likely need more help from this community to develop the code further when I need more features, and make sure that it still looks good.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you please expand a bit on why what you mean? What do you mean by styles? 1. Doesn't the fact that the style is defined inside of the pic mean that it only has to be defined once? What is otherwise the purpose of defining a pic? 2. What should you use instead of `\tikzstyle` if that is deprecated? 3. What is it that is overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write Tikz code. To demonstrate the basic concepts, I show a flat 2D-solution, addressing **captions** and **rotation**. You can transform it into 3D-drawing, which doesn't alter these issues.

My prefered **coding style** is to draw in mini-steps, which are easy to follow. Of course, you can do more in one-go, i.e. with a single `\path` statement. Though that may be effective coding, it can obscure relevant details. So, at some point, the approach or philosophy becomes a matter of taste and experience. Other examples will show that, certainly.

I **suggest to compare** with the generated tikz-code. E.g. for the 2D version using `\pics` doesn't make much sense: there is little to re-use. But that's merely a matter of refactoring the code.

So, let's have a look at some details.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

`\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}` adjusts the page format, as needed. `\usepackage{graphicx}` I will need to import a graphic, see below. Save this drawing as `eur.png` in the same directory to run my code:

[image: eur.png]

`\nodes` display valid Latex-code inside the curly brackets. So the first and last include said image, at given coordinates. The options for the nodes are defined in the beginning, see final code below. However, the names should suggest to "format" an image-node and a node displaying this green object in the middle. If we need to remember the position of the placed node, as we often do, use a syntax like `(X)` to remember position `X`.

```
 % ~~~ objects ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[img] (L) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{eur}}; 
    \node[grn] (M) at (2,0) {};
    \node[img] (R) at (5,0) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{eur}};
```

By intention I used absolute coordinates, which is fine with a simple drawing like this. Morever, from a layouters point of view, I wanted control over the placement of the objects text-labels; as you will see, option `[txt]` takes care of multiline text, where you just use `\\` as in ordinary Latex-text:

```
 % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[txt] at (0,-2.5) {ERA-5};
    \node[txt] at (5,-2.5) {Temperature distribution\\parameters};
```

Finally, we need to put the networks dimensions by putting some more nodes with the `[nmb]` options for the numbers. Though you can relate everything to the anchor points of L, M and R, namely south and west, I found it more convenient to put them as absolute coordinates wrt the nodes center (L, M and R).

That's why the x- and yshift statements appear, as well as the rotation. The text size is `\tiny`, as specified within style `nmb`.

```
 % ~~~ dimensions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[nmb,yshift=-6mm] at (L) {300};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-7mm,rotate=90] at (L) {200};
    
    \node[nmb,yshift=-6mm] at (M) {300};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-8mm,yshift=-3mm] at (M) {200};

    \node[nmb,yshift=-16mm] at (R) {600};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-18mm,yshift=-3mm,rotate=90] at (R) {400};
```

For simplicity I left the connecting arrows as is. It's no big deal to rework those lines, turning the arrow into green, with a larger linewidth and repositioning the arrow. Again, you probably start modifying at one `\draw` statement, and once satisfied move those options into a new style with a fancy name, like `arr` (not shown).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    img/.style={draw,inner sep=.1mm},
    grn/.style={draw,fill=green!25,
                rectangle,minimum height=8mm,minimum width=10mm},
    txt/.style={align=center},
    nmb/.style={font=\tiny},
 ]
 % ~~~ objects ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[img] (L) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{eur}}; 
    \node[grn] (M) at (2,0) {};
    \node[img] (R) at (5,0) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{eur}}; 

 % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw [->] (L) -- (M);
    \draw [->] (M) -- (R); 
    
 % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[txt] at (0,-2.5) {ERA-5};
    \node[txt] at (5,-2.5) {Temperature distribution\\parameters};
    
 % ~~~ dimensions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[nmb,yshift=-6mm] at (L) {300};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-7mm,rotate=90] at (L) {200};
    
    \node[nmb,yshift=-6mm] at (M) {300};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-8mm,yshift=-3mm] at (M) {200};

    \node[nmb,yshift=-16mm] at (R) {600};
    \node[nmb,xshift=-18mm,yshift=-3mm,rotate=90] at (R) {400};
 
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there some documentation for the options `img`, `grn`, `nmb` and `txt`? I can't find any of them in the [TikZ & PGF manual](https://saimei.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever, they are self-defined: `\begin{tikzpicture}[
    img/.style={draw,inner sep=.1mm},
    grn/.style={draw,fill=green!25,
                rectangle,minimum height=8mm,minimum width=10mm},
    txt/.style={align=center},
    nmb/.style={font=\tiny},
 ]` // as definded in the full code.

Comment: Ah, I see that you defined them in your last code snippet; now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but from your code, there is still very much that needs to be changed to get to the 3D-illustration that I want to have, and given what I have, I still feel like it will be significantly less work to just modify the code that I'm already using to fix the issues that I wanted to get fixed from the first place, than modifying your code to make it display the 3D illustration that I want. There are still several thins that are missing in your code; e.g. it is not 3D, I it doesn't explicitly set all side lengths, text doesn't automatically orient itself along edges, etc.

Comment: Do you see why that would make me still want to continue from the code that I already have rather than using your code, even if your design is actually better? Basically, from my perspective, I asked for help to fix the labels, and if I use your answer, I will end up with more problems than I originally had.

Comment: But maybe I could use some of the things you used in your answer to fix the positioning and size problem I had with the labels.

Comment: I think the only thing I don't know how to do is to orient what the code I started with call "zlabel" so that the text becomes aligned with the edge that goes along the diagonal in the illustration. I have tried to look at `Box.sty`, but I can't figure out why that text ends up at an angle, but not for example the "ylabel" text which is rendered horizontally while the edge it is displayed next to is vertical.

Comment: As far as I understand the 3d package, you just shift and rotate node text as usual, and the transformation cares for placement, including the illusion of a 3d rotation. Just focus on the right coordinate in the triplet and the planes canvas does the rest. // x is to the right, y to top, z „perpendicular“ towards the lower left.